# methods attached to an end statement?

Tags: ruby

I am playing some coding challenges on codewars, after you pass a challenge you get to see other peoples answers, and one looks like this:

```
def weirdcase(string)
  string.split(' ').map do |word|
    word.split('').each_with_index.map do |char, i|
      i % 2 == 0 ? char.upcase : char.downcase
    end.join('')
  end.join(' ')
end
```

The code runs just fine. I have never seen a method attached to an end like this. I'm curious about it. I would love to know more about this such as: Is this common? Is it considered good or bad practice? Why would this be preferable in a situation, if it is? What are some examples of methods one may want to chain to an end?

Comment: It is chained to `map` method, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method call isn't so much attached to the `end` keyword but rather to the result of the block that ends with the `end` keyword. Pretty much everything in Ruby returns a value, and pretty much every value is an object. As such, you can call methods on those values.

Comment: Oh I see! I'm used to seeing chaining happening with the syntax `object.method{block}.method.join('')` or something similar. I never even thought (nor have I seen) it done like this, so I didn't recognize what was really happening. Very interesting! thanks!

Comment: This is not quite right. It is a method's result, not the result of the method's block, that becomes the receiver for the method to which the method is chained. For each value a method passes to its block, the block performs a calculation (that typically depends on the value it receives) and returns the result of that calculation to the method. The block doesn't accumulate those results and then pass them on when it's method says it is finished.

Answer (score 2):

This is called method chaining. 
It performs the chained method on the result of the previous method.

For instance this calls the `.split` method on the `string` variable which returns an array which the `.map` method is called on.
`string.split(' ').map do |word|`